# Unable to access a page lying in different project of same solution in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to organise all my projects at one place and then will host on my IIS,so that I can access all of them from the same place.So what I have done I have made a solution file and in it I have added two websites.One is the mainWebsite which will have a list of my projects and by clicking on the particular link I will be taken to the home page of that website.I have tried this but not able to access the page of other website from my main website.Its saying the url or page not found.

Follwing is the main home page of my main website which have list of all projects

ProjectHome.aspx

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="~/AndroidAdmin/Default.aspx">Android Admin Methods</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">DineGenie Website</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">HR Payroll</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Following is the snapshot of my solution explorer.I am making these projects in Visual Studio 2012
[image]

Comment: How are you hosting these sites? Just in Visual Studio, or deployed to IIS as separate sites? Or deployed to IIS with one as virtual directory.

Comment: currently i am running it through visual studio

Comment: Looks like you're just launching the second site, so the AndroidAdmin site is not even running. For that reason it give you a 404. In production (IIS) you should create two different websites. In Visual Studio, you can launch both, but then they have their own directory since they are  two seperate sites, so this still won't work

Comment: This means there is no way to achieve this thing or suggest me something if possible so that I can achieve my goal